# Usar variável em uma execução

Tags: oracle, pl-sql

Eu estou criando a sequinte pl:

```
declare
  cont integer;
  tabela varchar2(100) := 'TABLE_TESTE';
  col varchar2(100) := 'TESTE';
begin
    SELECT COUNT(*) into cont FROM USER_TAB_COLUMNS
    WHERE TABLE_NAME = UPPER(tabela)
    AND COLUMN_NAME = UPPER(col);
   if cont = 0 then
       execute immediate 'ALTER TABLE tabela ADD col number(19,0)';
   end if;
end;
/
```

Como posso usar as variáveis `tabela` e `col` no `execute immediate`?

Comment: dá uma olhada aqui
http://www.sqlines.com/oracle-to-sql-server/execute_immediate

Answer (score 1):

Para comandos DML e blocos plsql o execute immediate aceita parâmetros diretamente no comando executado. Para setar o valor dos parâmetros é usado a declaração `using`.

```
declare
  vID integer;
begin
  vId := '1233456';
  execute immediate 'Delete from UMA_TABELA where ID_TABELA = :ID' using vID;
end;
```

Já no seu caso, como é um comando DDL não é permitido o uso de parâmetros, neste caso você precisa concatenar suas variáveis diretamente no comando. Ex:

```
execute immediate 'ALTER TABLE '|| tabela || ' ADD ' || col || ' number(19,0)';
```